# Trigger.io: Native Module Development

Tags: plugins, module, admob, native, trigger.io

We are using Native Module in order to display our ads to our gaming Application. We are using Mobfox SDK for the integration to our Mobile App. Though I can logcat and seems I can request to the admob, my problem now is how am I going to pass what admob returns by calling it to my javascript file?

```
public class API {

public static void requestAds(final ForgeTask task, @ForgeParam("pub_id") final String pub_id, @ForgeParam("state") final String state, @ForgeParam("type") final String type){

    final AdSize size;
    if (pub_id.length() == 0) {

        task.error("No Published ID entered");
        return;
    }

    if (type == "1"){
        size = AdSize.BANNER;   
    }else if (type == "2"){
        size = AdSize.IAB_BANNER;
    }else if (type == "3"){
        size = AdSize.IAB_LEADERBOARD;      
    }else if (type == "4"){ //my size
        size = AdSize.IAB_MRECT;
    }else if (type == "5"){
        size = AdSize.IAB_WIDE_SKYSCRAPER;
    }else if(type == "6"){
        size = AdSize.SMART_BANNER;
    }else{
        size = AdSize.BANNER;   
    }

    task.performUI(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            AdView adView = new AdView(ForgeApp.getActivity(), size, pub_id);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
            if(state == "TEST"){
                request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
            }
            adView.loadAd(request); 

        }
    });


}
```

Now, what I want is to get the values of `adView.loadAd(request);`. How am I going to do it so that I can display and pass it to my js file? For example, I want it to be the return value to my `success function()`, Is it possible? Can you please guide us on how doing it?

Thanks, waiting for your reply.

Comment: For those of us not familiar with admob or mobfox, what is  adView.loadAd() returning? Is it just a banner image?

Answer (score 1):

To return a value to javascript you can use the `success` method on the task object passed into your API method. You can call this with a `String` or a `JsonElement`. i.e.

```
task.success("This string will be passed to the success callback in JS");
```

Comment: Hello @Connorhd, Is it possible to send other than string or json?

Comment: Have a look at the [native module API docs](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/native/android/reference/io/trigger/forge/android/core/ForgeTask.html#success()). task.success() can be used to return either nothing, String, Boolean or a JsonElement.